# How to stabilize features over time?

Tags: random-variable, feature-engineering, engineering-statistics

I have in my model some features,  which seem to have some super power to explain the training data. To be more specific, the model is to predict clicks and the features are the click-through-rate(CTR) of some granularity. The CTRs of certain granularity are the same in both training and testing set.

Althought we gained a lot of precision in training set by adding such features, the performance gain in testing set was limited. Because I seperated training/testing dataset over time, so I suspected that it was caused by feature being unstable over time. (and I also verified this hypothesis by calculating granularity CTR over different period).

So my question is how to stablize such features, and if it is not possible, how shall we draw a conclusion whether such feature is only noise?